# Why are women restricted from entering temples during menstruation?

Tags: belief, temple, rituals, tradition, women

Women are restricted from entering temples or any other holy places during their menstruation. Why so?

This is the normal biological function of every female of every mammalian species. If talking about the abdominal/leg pain or the hormonal changes or may be weakness, why restrict? Rather why not give an option to them?

Nobody ever prohibited a woman from going to office or workplace during her periods. Then why not temples?

Comment: It has nothing to do with religion or purity but it is related to cleanliness, health and hygienic. And it is followed since ancient time. During ancient time, there were no hygienic dress, chemical available in market during menstruation and blood was considered as evil thing inside temple. So only even now sacrifice for god is done outside temple. Since then we follow same without questioning anything.

Comment: To give the women complete rest during the periods. Read the full explanation here in the Q&A with Sri Sri Ravi Shankar:
http://www.artofliving.org/only-giving-there-happiness